# How to "call" a batch file with space in pathname

Tags: windows, batch

Inside a batch script, I want to call another batch script as follows:

```
call C:\Users\user name\test.cmd
call "C:\Users\user name\test.cmd"
```

The first doesn't work since there's a space in the file path, and the second doesn't work because `call` tries to execute the entire string with double quotes.

Is there a way to do this without using `start`?

Edit, more context:

```
:runAndAssertCmd
    echo Running: %1
    call %~1 || exit /b
goto:eof

call :runAndAssertCmd "C:\Users\user name\bower install"
```

This will give the error,

```
'C:\Users\user' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it without `call`?

Comment: Doing it without `call` creates a different error (The system cannot find the batch label specified), since I pass in the path into a function that actually `call`s it.

Comment: Your second syntax (with double-quotes) is correct. Can you provide more of the surrounding code?

Comment: More context added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sub-routine `runAndAssertCmd` line replace `%~1` with just `%1` as the former removes quotes which you wish to keep.

Comment: This seems to try and execute the string with double quotes, as I noted in the question. The error is: `'"C:\Users\user name\bower install"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: There is no extension on the called exectuable.

Comment: I added the extension and got the same error. `'"C:\Users\user name\bower.cmd install"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.

Comment: You need the close quote after .cmd "install" is a parameter so add %2 to your subroutine